# How to validate values entered in the TEdit and how to restrict TMaskEdit to allow only numbers?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need help with doing validation for certain controls.

***Question 1:***
I have a TEdit control on my form. I would like to check whether the data entered by the user is either an alphabet or a number.

***Question 2:***
I have a TMaskEdit control on my form and I want to restrict users to enter only numbers.

Can anybody post code samples how to do that ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a TEdit control in my form. I would like to check
>   whether the data entering by the user is either an alphabet
>   or a number.

Look at the `TryStrToInt()` function in the SysUtils unit.  If it returns True, the text is a valid number.

> I have a TMaskEdit control in my form . and I want the user to enter only numbers.

Read the documentation on how the `TMaskEdit.EditMask` property works.  Set the mask to contain as many `'#'` characters as you want to allow users to enter digits.

Altrnatively, switch to `TEdit` and use the `SetWindowsLong()` function to give it the `ES_NUMBER` style.